# how to use Alert Box?

Tags: android, dialog

I have an application that uses data stored on the SD card, but my problem, I want to display a dialog box with error message before the application terminates. I tried to create a dialog box not in activity but in a simple class. the code that i use is unkown. for the first part and the second every thing is ok. when the SD card is installed and when i use a nexus google Tablet. I would like to have a message that their is no SDCard before that application crashed, or to start an other Activity used to tell the user that application need an Sdcard. the code that i use is given below. My application print the Log the crash when their is no SDcard.

```
public File getRootDirectory()


 {
        if (this.rootDirectory == null)
        {
            File sdCardRoot = MainApplication.getInstance().getSDCardRootDirectory();
            if (sdCardRoot != null)
            {
                this.rootDirectory = sdCardRoot;
            }
            else if(Build.BRAND.equals("google"))
            {
                this.rootDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(MainApplication.Appli_DIRECTORY);
            } else {
                Log.d(CLASS_TAG, " their is no  carte Sd ");


                /**
                 * I am trying to start a Fail Activity 
                 */
                //Intent intent = new Intent(context, FailActivity.class)
                //.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
                //context.startActivity(intent); 

            }
            Log.i(CLASS_TAG, "Root directory set to :" + this.rootDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        return this.rootDirectory;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

    if(!isSDPresent)
    {
      // yes SD-card is present

     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setMessage("Sorry,SD Card not Found")
                   .setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       finish();
                       }
                   });
            builder.setCancelable(false);
                   // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
            builder.create();
            builder.show();


    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably you must create the alertbox in the UI Thread.